# iOS: jQuery mobile Date picker showing text keyboard input for a moment

Tags: ios, jquery-mobile, datebox

Iam using phonegap 2.2.0 and jQuery mobile 1.2.0.
Here is my Date picker html,

```
<input class="dateField entry-time ui-input-text ui-body-d ui-shadow-inset ui-corner-all ui-icon-datebox" type="text" data-role="datebox" data-options="{"mode": "flipbox", "useNewStyle": true, "useFocus": true, "beforeToday": true}" readonly="readonly">
```

When I tested in iOS7 and 6 I got native text input keyboard  for a moment, then got the native datepicker keyboard.
how to fix this?

Comment: replace type="text" with type="date" and remove readonly="readonly"

Comment: its crashing sometimes!, date picker RHS side shows "Done" then switches to "clear","Close" buttons, sometimes not opening at all.

Comment: use simple <input type="date" name="mydate"/ >